# Count number of rows in another dataframe

Tags: r, merge, count, tidyverse

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:5, var1=c("c3e", "d3r", "ff2", "dfl", "df4"))
df2 <- data.frame(id=1:10, var1=c("d3r", "d3r", "c3e", "dfl", "dfl", "dfl", "c3e", "df4", "c3e", "c3e"))
```

How can I best create a new column in `df1` giving the number of appearances of each value of `df1$var1` in `df2`? E.g. 'c3e' appears four times, 'd3r' twice etc.

Comment: `c3e` appears 4 times, no?

Comment: @LAP, that won't respect the order. It's safer to merge, i.e. `merge(df1, as.data.frame(table(df2$var1)), by.x = "var1", by.y = "Var1", all.x = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1$count <- table(df2$var1)[df1$var1]
df1$count[is.na(df1$count)] <- 0          # change NA to 0

df1
#   id var1 count
# 1  1  c3e     4
# 2  2  d3r     2
# 3  3  ff2     0
# 4  4  dfl     3
# 5  5  df4     1
```

@Jaap had also a nice suggestion:

```
df1$count <- table(factor(df2$var1, levels = df1$var1))
```

Comment: Another possibility: `table(factor(df2$var1, levels = df1$var1))`

Comment: Thank you @Jaap! That is even nicer! :)

Answer (score 3):

We can loop through each value of `df1$var1` and calculate number of times that value occur in `df2`s `var1`.

```
df1$count <- sapply(df1$var1, function(x) sum(df2$var1 %in% x))

df1
#  id var1 count
#1  1  c3e     4
#2  2  d3r     2
#3  3  ff2     0
#4  4  dfl     3
#5  5  df4     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2)[df1, .N,  on = .(var1), by = .EACHI],
                 count := N , on = .(var1)]
df1
#   id var1 count
#1:  1  c3e     4
#2:  2  d3r     2
#3:  3  ff2     0
#4:  4  dfl     3
#5:  5  df4     1
```